# websphere portal portlet preference not showing up in config

Tags: portlet

I have added parameters in portlet.xml. It does not show up in the configuration of the portlet. I am signed in as admin.

```
<preference>
    <name>isDisablePortlet</name>
    <value>false</value>
</preference>
<preference>
    <name>disablePortletText</name>
    <value>xxxx</value>
</preference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just edit the preference on the file system after deployment. Values are only read at deploy time. After it is deployed you must use the admin area of the portal server or create a config mode for your portlet.